# Unable to access datasource mbeans via jmx in wildfly swarm/thorntail

Tags: jmx, wildfly-swarm, thorntail

I'm trying to enable JMX for my wildfly swarm component. I'm used to seeing several mbeans for a variety of wildfly subsystems, I'm specifically interested in the data source mbeans.

I've pasted a snippet below, I've got the jmx fraction and I have `statistics-enabled` set to true. When thorntail is running I can connect to the JVM via JMX, but I am cannot see any datasource mbeans. Is there something else that needs to be enabled for them to show up?

The app is currently on swarm 2018.2.0.Final

```
swarm:
  jmx:
    expression-expose-model.domain-name: RemoteJMX
    jmx-remoting-connector:
      use-management-endpoint: true
    resolved-expose-model.domain-name: RemoteJMX
    show-model: true
  datasources:
    data-sources:
      MyDataSourceName:
        driver-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver
        connection-url: jdbc:xyz
        statistics-enabled: true
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, WildFly Swarm 2018.2.0.Final is *very* old. In the meantime, WildFly Swarm got renamed to Thorntail; you can automatically migrate by running `mvn io.thorntail:thorntail-maven-plugin:2.5.0.Final:migrate-from-wildfly-swarm`.

And then: if you connect to JMX, do you see any WildFly MBeans at all? I mean, is the problem with datasources only, or is it more general?

During boot, you should see JMX-related log messages, such as `JMX not configured for remote access` or `JMX configured for remote connector: implicitly using ... interface`. Do you see any of them?

Finally, it seems you want JMX exposed on the management port. Do you have a dependency on the `management` fraction?

Comment: I know I'm on an older version, and it is getting upgraded soon.

Comment: I have found the issue anyway. Bit of an odd one. I was connecting using standard jmx, rather than http-remoting-jmx which apparently gives different beans. I do the managmenet fraction installed, so now when I connected with http-remoting-jmx I can see all the mbeans I need. Thanks.